# Should I keep Steenee in my team?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

When my Bounsweet evolved into Steenee, she is still grass type and I heard grass types are bad. Is best to keep my Steenee and evolve her, or should I keep Steenee in my box/PC?

Comment: (I am asking if she is worth it or will be a waste of room)

Comment: Which of the pokemon games?

Comment: Bounsweet is a new pokemon in sun and moon so I've re-tagged the question as [pokemon-sm].

Answer (score 1):

Grass types are not very good offensively, true, as grass moves are resisted by seven other types. But they are a core component of many teams because of their unique resistances.

Water types are extremely common and grass-types counter them pretty well. Most of them can also learn ice-type moves, but during an ingame play through, the vast majority of them will not have any.

Grass also has a rare resistance to ground, another common offensive type. Only grass and bug resist ground, and grass can also hit ground-types back super effectively.

Grass-types also have a useful resistance to electric-type moves.

A very popular "core" to build a team around is the fire-water-grass core, as they cover each other's weaknesses well.